# Increase Width of Data Validation List

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

How can I increase the width of a Data Validation List while keeping the cell width as smaller as possible ?

Comment: What do you mean? You want the cell, say, 10px wide, but the data validation list that drops down from that to be larger, say 100px wide?

Comment: Items in my drop down lists seems to be cut off and do not show the entire list. So I need to increase the width of the drop down to fit the content, while keeping the cell width as small as possible because its a large spreadsheet.

Comment: I believe you can't do that using data validation. You can try automating it using a dropdown / listbox / combobox and some worksheet event(s).

Comment: take a look at this [solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46484835/change-width-of-data-validation-dropdown/46485103#46485103)

Comment: Is there any solution for the above question? I have tried with the solutions provided here, But none of them does not solve my problem.